# Глобальный указатель на объект

Tags: c++, qt

Какие могут быть подводные камни если сделать глобальный указатель на объект по типу Sensormanager *sensormanager и передать его во второй поток. Определять его видимость через extern в других диалоговых окнах, по типу extern Sensormanager *sensormanager . Цель: иметь возможность сделать связь сигнал - слот из любого диалогового окна или просто сделать обращение к слоту по типу sensormanager->slot со вторым потоком. Или лучше использовать синглет для этих целей?

Comment: Сделайте в диалоговых окнах публичными нужные вам сигналы, и выполняйте `connect` извне диалогового окна, при его создании

Comment: Если к объекту и его состоянию в любой момент времени будет иметь доступ только один поток, то ничего страшного не произойдет. Проблемы будут при параллельном доступе к изменении состояния объекта из разных потоков. Вы можете уточнить структуру вашего проекта, что делает второй поток, сколько их (кроме главного) и так далее. А то вы сыпите разрозненными вопросами, а общая картина остается непонятной.

Comment: Второй поток один. Во втором потоки происходит опрос датчиков. Процесс достаточно медленный. И доступ к датчикам может произойти из любого диалогового окна. Вторых потоков всего один. Могу добавить еще второй поток для  вывода прогресс бара, или чтение файла. Поэтому к глобально переменной будет только доступ из главного потока.

Answer (score 1):

Недюсь я правильно понял ваши трудности из нескольких вопросов и поэтому рекомендую отделить GUI от логики работы приложения (то есть второго потока, третьего, записей в файлы, чтения из сети и так далее).

Пусть у вас имеется несколько окон (Главное MainWindow в нем Dialog1, Dialog2, первом диалоге поддиалог Dialog11), а также отдельно поток (ваш номер 2) SensorManager (основной поток приложения мы подразумеваем).

Вариант 1. Можно сделать общие интерфейсы сигналов и слотов через посредника ГУИ и отдельного посредника Логики.

Пусть у нас для ГУИ посредником служит главное окно приложения:

```
class MainWindow ... {
    MainWindow() {
        connect(&dialog1, SIGNAL(signal1()), 
                this, SIGNAL(signal1FromDialog1()));
        connect(&dialog1, SIGNAL(signal1Dialog11()), 
                this, SIGNAL(signal1FromDialog11()));
        ...
    }
signals:
    void signal1FromDialog1();
    void signal2FromDialog1();
    void signal3FromDialog1(<какие-то аргументы>);

    void signal1FromDialog11(); // ! От Dialog11

    void signal1FromDialog2();
    void signal2FromDialog2(<какие-то аргументы>);

    и так далее
public slots:
    // Для слотов диалога 1
    void callSlot1Dialog1(<аргуенты и без них>) {
        dialog1.callSlot1(...);
    }
    void callSlot2Dialog1(<аргуенты и без них>) { ... }
    // Для слотов поддиалога 1 диалога 1, то есть для Dialog11
    void callSlot3Dialog11(<аргуенты и без них>) {
        dialog1.callDialog11Method1(...);
    }

    // Для слотов диалога 2
    void callSlot1Dialog2(<аргуенты и без них>) {
        dialog2.callSlot1(...)
    }
    void callSlot2Dialog2(<аргуенты и без них>) { ... }

    и так далее
private:
    Dialog1 dialog1;
    Dialog2 dialog2;
    ...
}
```

Тоже самое для логики:

```
class Logic : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void someSignalFromThread(<Здесь могли бы быть ваши аргументы>);
public slots:
    void callSlotForThread() {
       sensorManager->someSlot();
    }
private:
    SensorManager* sensorManager;
}
```

Далее мы все это хозяйство сшиваем/соединяем:

```
void main() {
    MainWindow window;
    Logic logic;

    QObject::connect(&window, SIGNAL(signal1FromDialog1()), 
                     &logic, SLOT(callSlotForThread()));
    еще коннект за маму,
    еще коннект за папу,

    Коннект из логики в окно
    QObject::connect(&logic, SIGNAL(signal1SensorManager()), 
                     &window, SLOT(callSlotForDialog1()));
    еще коннект из логики, (может быть вы добавите третий поток и т.д.)

    ...

    return a.exec();
}
```

Вариант 2. Мы не делаем общий интерфейс слотов, сигналов, а предоставляем сами объекты окон, диалогов, потоков и тому подобное. Тогда main будет выглядеть так:

```
void main() {
    MainWindow window;
    Logic logic;

    ...
    QObject::connect(&window.dialog1(), SIGNAL(signal1FromDialog1()), 
                     &logic, SLOT(callSlot1ForThread()));
    QObject::connect(&window.dialog1().dialog11(), SIGNAL(signal1FromDialog11()), 
                     &logic, SLOT(callSlot2ForThread()));

    ИЛИ!

    QObject::connect(&window.dialog1(), SIGNAL(signal1FromDialog1()), 
                     logic.sensorManager(), SLOT(callSlot1()));
    ...

    return a.exec();
}
```

Вариант 3. Отдельные окна и диалоги и поддиалоги, и отдельное их связывание друг с другом, но для средних (больше 4-5 объектов) и больших приложений это плохая идея.

Надеюсь идея ясна

Comment: Примерно понял. У меня вопрос а как вы будите открывать окна     Dialog1 dialog1;
    Dialog2 dialog2; если нужно перейти сначала в dialog1 а из него в  dialog2 ?

Comment: @zhilenkov я не совсем понял в чем тут трудность?  Можно же сделать цепочку вызовов, либо прямых `dialog1.callDialog2() { dialog2.callMethod(); }`, либо через сигналы/слоты

Comment: Можно более подробно про цепочку вызовов?

Comment: @zhilenkov dialog1 имеет поле dialog11, когда у него вызывают метод, то в нем мы вызываем метод внутреннего поля: `dialog1.method() { dialog11.method(); }` и так далее. Это же базовые вещи

Comment: Вот по аналогии в си есть глобальные переменные и локальные. Глобальные переменные видны всем функциям. Локальные видны только в теле функции. Не берем во внимание static. Говорим только про видимость. Вот по аналогии мне нужен второй поток но с глобальной видимостью. Чтобы я мог из любого окна обратиться к нему. Вот и все.

Comment: Перехожу в диалог1  назвал его "menu_1" . Ваш эквивалент "dialog1"
    menu_1* dialog = new menu_1(0);
    dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    dialog->exec();
В "menu_1"  хочу сделать связь сигнал --- слот с "sensormanager" . Для этого мне нужно в  "menu_1" указать объект  "sensormanager" но "menu_1" его не знает.

Comment: @zhilenkov вы можете связывать объекты уровнем выше, например в главном окне приложения, где эти диалоги являются соответственно полями этого окна. Не воспринимайте мой ответ буквально это просто образец-схема работы. Я же не знаж точную структуру вашего приложения

Comment: У меня не десктоп а промышленный пк. С маленьким дисплеем. У меня все окна накладываются друг на друга. По типу бутерброда. Главное окно всегда снизу ---> Menu_1 ----> setting и т.д. Не знаю как еще объяснить.

Comment: А вот интересно qt для мобильных приложений подходит? Там же тоже работа получается с окнами экран та маленький у телефона. Там также из окна в окно переходят. И вложенных окон может быть очень много.

Comment: Alexander Chernin может я вам проект отошлю вы посмотрите?  А там более понятно будет?

Comment: @zhilenkov киньте ссылку. Но незнаю когда посмотрю НГ все ж

Comment: Вот https://yadi.sk/d/w3tLR0m-2rdTaQ   Я вам все расскажу

Comment: Мне только связь сигналы --- слоты. Передача указателя на второй поток.

Comment: А можно как то наследовать    
 dialog2;
при переходе из окна   dialog1; в dialog2;?

Comment: Я опираюсь на ваш пример (Вариант 1. Можно сделать общие интерфейсы сигналов и слотов через посредника ГУИ и отдельного посредника Логики.

Пусть у нас для ГУИ посредником служит главное окно приложения:). Вот хочу перейти из MainWindow в dialog1 а потом из dialog1 в dialog2. Как это сделать? Напишите пример. Хочу понять как выстраивать дерево.

Comment: @zhilenkov какое дерево? Короче, посмотрел я ваш код и могу сказать, что объяснять вам придется слишком многое и SO не то место, где это можно сделать. В принципе вам все ответы выданы, ничего такого особенного я в вашем проекте не увидел - небольшое оконное приложение. Подумайте об архитектуре в первую очередь, опирайтесь на ООП. Возьмите карандаш и бумагу и порисуйте связи между сущностями в приложении и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

> Какие могут быть подводные камни если сделать глобальный указатель на
>   объект по типу Sensormanager *sensormanager и передать его во второй
>   поток

Подводные камни? Конфликт между потоками при доступе к глобальному объекту. Если два или более потока будут осуществлять доступ к одному и тому же участку памяти, и один из потоков будет вызывать изменение этой памяти, то будет существовать состояние гонки и, как следствие, неопределённое поведение, за исключением случаев, когда:

- обе операции являются атомарными, или
- выполнение операций синхронизировано друг с другом (для этих целей подходит `std::mutex`).

Это будет верно для любого объекта (не обязательно глобального), к которому будут иметь доступ два или более потока, так как в C++ любой поток всегда может обратиться к любому объекту, существующему в программе, если адрес этого объекта был каким-либо способом передан этому потоку.

Обеспечьте потоко-безопасность путём добавления мьютексов во все методы чтения/записи объекта.

В этом примере доступ к `Object::value_` защищён `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`, и два или более потока могут безопасно одновременно вызвать методы `set` и `get`.

```
class Object
{
public:
    void set(const std::string & content);
    std::string get();

private:
    std::string value_;
    std::mutex mtx_;
};

void Object::set(const std::string & content)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
    value_ = content;
}

std::string Object::get()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
    return value_;
}
```

Comment: ВЛ 80 а как правильно закрывать второй поток в случаи использования глобального указателя?

Comment: @zhilenkov, мне довольно не просто ответить на этот вопрос, не зная подробностей вашего кода. Но сам факт того, что объект является глобальным, не должен влиять на правила закрытия потоков.