# выделение глобального указателя для второго потока в qt4.7.8

Tags: c++, qt

По аналогии в си есть глобальные переменные и локальные. Глобальные переменные видны всем функциям. Локальные видны только в теле функции. Не берем во внимание static. Говорим только про видимость. Вот по аналогии мне нужен второй поток но с глобальной видимостью в qt4.7.8. Чтобы я мог из любого диалогового окна обратиться к нему. Для этого хочу использовать глобальный указатель на второй поток. Какие есть подводные камни у этого метода? Или лучше использовать синглтон?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Любая глобальная сущность вредит дизайну программы. Разбор этого утверждения есть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510910/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82).

Задуманное вами в Qt (всех версий) реализуется при помощи сигналов и слотов, в том числе и общение между потоками.

Comment: Я понимаю что мешает. Я не понимаю как сделать глобальный доступ к потоку с помощью сигналов и слотов. Вот чтобы можно было из любого окна обратиться к потоку. Может есть какой пример.

Comment: @zhilenkov я вам расписывал как это можно сделать, ничего сложного https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1063440/235611

Comment: Может я не совсем понял ваш ответ. Но мне показалось что это не совсем то. Я не понял как мне обратиться к указателю на второй поток из N диалогового окна? У меня в N диалоговом окне не будет указателя на второй поток. Понимаете. Через конструктор указатель передавать тоже не удобно.

Comment: Я добавил к вашему комментарию вопрос.

Comment: В ваших окнах делаете сигналы и слоты, и про создании привязываете их к вашему объекту.

Что вам мешает передавать указатель?

Comment: ну сделайте глобальный указатель на поток и вызывайте его слоты через `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`

Comment: Мне кажется это не совсем удобная конструкция. 
Когда я нахожусь в окне "mainwindow" создаю второй бесконечный поток. По нажатию на кнопку перехожу в окно "menu_1". В окне "menu_1" можно сделать переход в окно "setting", "upgradefirmware" и т.д. При входе в окно setting мне нужно остановить второй поток. 

Вот мне нужно передать указатель на второй поток из окна "mainwindow" в окно "setting" для создания связи сигнал --- слот. И генерации сигнала для остановки. Можно передавать указатель сначала в окно "menu_1" а потом в окно "setting" но уж очень сложно мне кажется.